# Dynamically load collection name based on environment based properties in Spring Cloud GCP Data Firestore @Document annotation on the entity

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gcp

The setup is pretty much basic. There's an entity, a repository and a service that interacts with Google Cloud Firestore. The Entity's `@Document` annotation has the `collectionName` derived from the environment specific `application.properties` file.

When the `firestoreEntityRepository.findById(documentId)` call is made with a valid and available document id, we get a `null` return value. If the `collectionName` is hardcoded with a valid collection name of a specific environment, we get the appropriate document. So, this definitely has to do with the collection name not binding (or not initializing in the expected order) during runtime.

**Firestore Entity**

```
import com.google.cloud.firestore.annotation.DocumentId;
import com.google.cloud.spring.data.firestore.Document;

@Document(collectionName = "${api.firestore.collection}")
public class FirestoreEntity {
    @DocumentId
    String documentId;
    String fieldOne;
    String fieldTwo;
}
```

**Firestore Entity Repository**

```
import com.google.cloud.spring.data.firestore.FirestoreReactiveRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface FirestoreEntityRepository extends FirestoreReactiveRepository<FirestoreEntity> {
}
```

**Firestore Entity Service**

```
@Service
public class FirestoreEntityService {

    private final FirestoreEntityRepository firestoreEntityRepository;
    
    public FirestoreEntityService(FirestoreEntityRepository firestoreEntityRepository) {
        this.firestoreEntityRepository= firestoreEntityRepository;
    }

    public FirestoreEntity getFirestoreEntity(String documentId) {
        return firestoreEntityRepository
                .findById(documentId)
                .block();
    }
}
```

Apart from using the property name directly in the SpEL, I tried the following,

1. Populating a bean `FirestoreConfigProperties` using `@ConfigurationProperties("api.firestore")` annotation and the referring the bean name as in the collectionName as below,

> `@Document(collectionName = "#{@firestoreConfigProperties.getCollection()}")`

2. Use `systemProperties` and `environment` in the expression

```
@Document(collectionName = "#{@environment.getProperty('api.firestore.collection')}")

@Document(collectionName = "#{systemProperties['api.firestore.collection']}")
```

Nothing works. Please suggest me some ideas on how to implement this solution. Otherwise, I would've to abandon spring data and use the low level `Firestore` object to perform the operations.

Answer (score 0):

The feature is not available yet. I have found the GitHub issue here.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/1385